# C static variable behaviour in java

Tags: java, c, static

```
void func()
{
    static int a=10;
    println("\na is ::%d",a);
     a++;
}
int main(){
    int i=1;
    while(i<6){
        func();
    }
}
```

This would give the output as

```
10
11 
12
13
14
```

So this is the default behaviour of static variable in c.I want to know whether is there any inbuilt technique in java for the same behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried changing this to a Java program? As far as I can tell: yes, it works the same. `static` variables are class level, not instance level.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way...

```
class A
{
   static int a=0;
   static void func()
   {
        System.out.print("\na is ::%d",a);
        a++;
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        int i=1;
        while(i<6){
           func();
           i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `static int a=10;
   static void func()
   {
        System.out.printf("\na is ::%d",a);
        a++;
   }
`

Comment: YES ofcourse. But there seems no inbuilt method for this.

Comment: @Neuron The above snippet gives error as  `func() non static ,cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: @Intriguing Yes,Sorry because I was calling static variable from non static method which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class construct that, on instantiation, increments a static variable, then yes, the behavior will be the same.

Here's a snippet.

```
public class StaticExample {
    private static int val = 0;

    public StaticExample() {
        val++;
    }

    public static int getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

With the following iteration code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    new StaticExample();
    System.out.println(StaticExample.getVal());
}
```

...I get this result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```